# Set focus on textarea from DOM

Tags: angular

I want when ngIf fired then textarea gets focus. I don't want to do this with @ViewChildren (it loads project).

Now I have `(click)='myInput.focus()'`and this sets focus only click.. Also I tried this with `autofocus` but it's fired only one time and when ngIf is fired second time then autofocus doesn't work.

```
div *ngIf="i == editable && editCommentUp" (click)='myInput.focus()'>
         <div class="formCommentComment">
            <div class="formPanel">
            </div>
            <textarea #myInput id="formCommentComment" [(ngModel)]="comment.comment"></textarea>
         </div>
         <div class="wrapperFormButton">
            <button id="formCommentButton" (click)="editComment('/edit-comment', comment._id, comment.comment, i)"> Send </button>
            <button id="formCommentButtonCancel" (click)="cancel()"> Send</button>
            <i class="{{enterGood}} enterGood"> </i>
            <div class="errorMessage" style="margin: 10px 0 0;">{{errorMessage}}</div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Did you tried simple `autofocus` attribute? Refer this [url](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_input_autofocus.asp)

Comment: "Also I tried this with autofocus but it's fired only one time and when ngIf is fired second time then autofocus doesn't work."